# Ruby on rails - #<Resource:0x007f1004593600> weird message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I don't know why I get some weird message on my view when I try to assign a variable.

```
<%= column = local_assigns[:param] %>
```

This is what I get on my view:

```
#<Resource:0x007f1004593600> 

#<Resource:0x007f1004592e08> 

#<Resource:0x007f1004889eb8>
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the code to the following

```
<% column = local_assigns[:param] %>
```

and you should not get the error message. I've basically removed the "=" symbol after the first <%. The "="symbol implies that the value of "column" will be printed to the screen.

Without the "=" symbol, the code executes without printing any output.